ZFS folder very slow after having many files
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 using ZFS for my filesystems. This is on a laptop whose only storage device is a WD Black SN850X NVMe card. The default Ubuntu installation process configured two ZFS pools:
                                          capacity     operations     bandwidth 
pool                                    alloc   free   read  write   read  write
--------------------------------------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
bpool                                    187M  1.69G      0      0    381    204
  86349523-abd9-7a45-ab84-60d7622c240f   187M  1.69G      0      0    381    204
--------------------------------------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
rpool                                    286G   634G     13     31  1.11M   796K
  cc31ec4d-1dd2-ed4f-9f90-fa99ec5aa3a2   286G   634G     13     31  1.11M   796K
--------------------------------------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----

/tmp is part of the root mount, which is in rpool.
My /tmp folder briefly had over 2 million files in it due to a bug in some code. When there were this many files in it, performance took a nosedive -- even just listing files (without sorting) would pause for upwards of a second. I removed most of the files, and things are back down to a manageable level now. But, operations on the list of files in /tmp are still slow.
When I time ls --sort=none on e.g. /bin, which has 2,842 entries it, I get something like:
real    0m0.088s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.075s

But the same command on /tmp, which currently has 4,444 entries:
real    0m0.472s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.446s

It seems that briefly housing 2 million files has left a permanent impact on the structure of /tmp? Is there a way to fix this? Do I just need to make a new /tmp and cut over to it??

Please edit your question to describe the disks that make up the pool, and if /tmp is its own dataset.  Such as  zpool iostat -v  output.

Please consider profiling call graphs to show what is on CPU, which can narrow in what exactly the sys time is doing.   Linux perf can record this many times a second for a specific command, then generate a nice visualization:   perf record -a -g -F 99 ls /tmp && perf script report flamegraph      https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Flame_Graph

Okay, perf record runs without errors, but perf script report flamegraph says "Please specify a valid report script". It says to use perf script -l to list scripts, but that command just says Check "PERF_EXEC_PATH" env to set scripts dir.

It appears that Ubuntu doesn't come with perf built in the way needed to produce a flame graph. perf doesn't think that Python is installed, and says that it needs to be rebuilt from source after installing Python. There is definitely some installation of Python on this system, though. Not sure what to do next.

After some fudging and uncoordinated plonking about, I have managed to produce a flame graph of listing the directory. https://i.imgur.com/YC3M2D1.png

I tried to grab a comparison with a directory that doesn't exhibit the problem, but its call to iterate_dir completed so fast that it wasn't captured in a single sample. :-P

I now have the answer to this. So, yes, it is a known issue. In the internal terminology of ZFS, "if ZAP records are deleted such that an entire leaf block of the ZAP object is emptied, the block is not reclaimed." But, not only is it a known issue, but it is a fixed issue. :-) The fix isn't yet in any shipping version but is expected to be soon.
This is the fix:
https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/pull/15888

Somewhere above millions of files in a directory, performance will be much worse. Does not really matter which file system or how many IOPS in the block device. POSIX semantics mean a significant overhead to maintain the file in directory concept. Which then becomes an exercise in understanding file system internals.
From your flame graph, not surprised that most of the stacks originates in  readdir calls.  I am surprised that the top level, actually taking the time, is mostly LZ4 uncompress. Which is a fast algorithm.   Hundreds of milliseconds of CPU time doing that implies lots of metadata, or lots of calls to getdents64, or something else being slow.
From what little I understand about ZFS on disk format, datasets have their own sets of objects.  So yes, you could make a new tmp dataset out of the root pool and mount that over the existing /tmp.  Copying data not required, as it is temporary files.
Or a tmpfs on /tmp. Simplify things by removing both ZFS and block devices.
Way too late to prevent this too many files problem, but OpenZFS does have object quotas. groupquota@group to set, and zfs userspace to list.  Also can be set per user or project.

Okay -- just to be clear, it's not that performance is bad with a huge number of files. It's that performance remains bad after the number of files drops back down. You have a directory with a scant few thousand files, and listing it takes half a second.

Also, I don't think placing a hard limit on the files in /tmp would be a good thing here. It would solve one problem -- the directory growing too much -- at the expense of a whole host of other problems -- many applications that expect to be able to create a temporary file are generally going to really misbehave if they can't do so. :-P

I don't know enough about zfs internals to say what exactly the metadata is that persists after deleting files. How big the ZAP data structures are so ZPL could have 2 million objects.  But it is plausible it got expensive.   And in this situation resetting to an empty file system (dataset) is easy.

So hey, this is pretty cool. Turns out it's actually a fixed issue and the fix will probably be in the next version of ZFS I end up using. https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/pull/15888
